# How to prevent size_t from being interpreted as reference?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, implicit-conversion

How can I change the signature of `distanceTo(..)` to make the compiler warn or error on a call with `std::size_t` as parameter?

```cpp
class Point {
private:
  float value;

public:
  Point(float value) : value(value){};
  float distanceTo(const Point &point) { return point.value - value; }
};

int main() {

  std::size_t index = 1;
  Point start(1);
  Point end(4);
  float dist = start.distanceTo(index); // compiles, but should not!
  std::cout << dist;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is: "How to prevent implicit type conversion?" (You should adjust the title)

Comment: Yeah, `Point` is not pointer.

Comment: Users LogicStuff and cpluplusrat posting time differs only in split second. LogicStuff added explanations and links afterwards.

Comment: @LogicStuff: question does not refer Point class, but `const Point&` which I did not name reference but pointer due to my C thinking in C++.

Comment: @DieterLücking: I was not aware of that until I read the answers. That is why I want to leave it like that, because it describes the symptom.

Comment: @VisorZ Whether `point` gets passed by value or reference doesn't really matter here. Conversion semantics are the same. Note that passing `size_t` does not make `&point` equal to it. The constructor takes it, then the temporary object binds to const reference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make the constructor [`explicit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit):

```
explicit Point(float value) : value(value) {} // no semicolon here
```

This disallows implicit conversions (from `size_t` through `float` to `Point`), but note that it also makes code such as `start.distanceTo(3.14)` and `Point p = 3.14;` invalid.

Answer (score 4):

Make the constructor explicit. Change `Point(float value)` to `explicit Point(float value)` and the problem will go away.